# Trying to warn if sending from a personal email account

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to prompt if sending from a personal account in Outlook.
I have the following which works 90% of the time, however sometimes it errors with the following:

> You cannot send an item that is already in the process of being sent

Code for reference:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim Send_Address As String
Dim Prompt As String

' Check Send_From name
Send_Address = Item.SendUsingAccount

Select Case Send_Address
    Case "example@domain.uk"
    Case Else

        Prompt = "You are currently sending this email from " & Send_Address & "" & vbNewLine & "Do you want to proceed?"
        If MsgBox(Prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If

End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't cast an instance of the `Account` class to a string:

```
Dim Send_Address As String
Dim Prompt As String

' Check Send_From name
Send_Address = Item.SendUsingAccount
```

The `SendUsingAccount` property returns or sets an `Account` object that represents the account under which the MailItem is to be sent. The `SendUsingAccount` property can be used to specify the account that should be used to send the `MailItem` when the `Send` method is called. This property returns `Null` (`Nothing` in Visual Basic) if the account specified for the `MailItem` no longer exists. For example, here is a sample use case:

```
Sub SendUsingAccount() 
 Dim oAccount As Outlook.account
 For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts
 If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then 
 Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
 Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
     oMail.Subject = "Sent using POP3 Account" 
     oMail.Recipients.Add ("someone@example.com") 
     oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll 
 Set oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount 
     oMail.Send 
 End If 
 Next 
End Sub
```

So, to check the SMTP address you need to use the following code:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim account as Outlook.Account
Dim Send_Address As String
Dim Prompt As String

' Check Send_From name
Set account = Item.SendUsingAccount

If Not account Is Nothing then 

   Send_Address = account.SmtpAddress

Select Case Send_Address
    Case "example@domain.uk"
    Case Else

        Prompt = "You are currently sending this email from " & Send_Address & "" & vbNewLine & "Do you want to proceed?"
        If MsgBox(Prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If

End Select

End If

End Sub
```